# tfidf vectorizer outputs all Zero

Tags: python, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I have a dataframe where one of the columns is text. I want to convert it using tfidf vectorizer. Below code where the text column is `complaint`

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, min_df=5,ngram_range=(1, 2), stop_words='english')
complain_features = tfidf.fit_transform(df.complaint.values.astype('str')).toarray()
```

When I print `complain_features` it outputs all zero. So when I convert this is pandas dataframe it is all NaN

```
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Can anyone please suggest what am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure it is all zeros, have you tried summing the rows or cols? Could it be that all the non-zero values are hidden by thos `...`s?

Comment: The same happened for me. I made sure all components are zero

Comment: In my case I was passing the wrong vocabulary: the documents did not contain any word defined in the vocabulary. In your case, it's very likely that the restriction that `min_df=5`, is so restrictive that no term satisfies being a minimum of 5 times, which is why you wouldn't have any word in the vocabulary. Maybe?